# camera not authorized in React-native-qr-code-scanner

Tags: javascript, react-native

Not able to see camera in React-native-qr-code-scanner , instead of camera it is showing camera not authorized text. I am using the same code which is there in npm react native qr code scanner documentation . I have tested in many devices.

Comment: which device you are testing ?

Comment: I have tested on Moto version 5.1 and also version 7.0 and RedmiNote3 version 5.1 .

Comment: Did you set the permission ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

Comment: yes i have added both vibrate and camera permissions in the manifest .

Comment: Have you ever test it with cameraProps={{captureAudio: false}}?

Comment: Yes , I have tested by adding cameraProps={{captureAudio: false}} , but it's not working . It is not showing the camera itself . only it is showing the text camera not authorized.

Comment: hi @Nethra, what's your solution find about " camera not authorized" ?. i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem it's last days......

1/ **npm uninstall react-native-camera**
2/ install a specific version of react-native-camera like this: **npm install react-native-camera@1.10.1**
3/the version in your package.json should look like this: **"react-native-camera": "1.10.1"**
4/ re-test

this has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue in iOS by doing the following

1. Change the versions

```
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
"react-native-permissions": "^3.0.5",
"react-native-camera": "3.44.3",
```

2. Info.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
```

3. Pod file

```
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'
```

4. yarn and pod install

Build app again it will work